# How do I determine which surface energy of a crystal silicon planes is the lowest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nanoscience

If a thin 8” Diameter Single Crystal Silicon (001) substrate is accidentally dropped onto a concrete floor, it will break apart into pieces.

By considering only the surface energies of (001), (110) and (111) planes, identify the likely planes that will be exposed on the broken Si pieces and hence describe the shape of the broken pieces.

Comment: What background information have you already reviewed about how the energies of single crystal planes of solids are calculated? References have the energies posted. What is not clear about the values on such sites?